# Insert a linebreak in a Google Spreadsheet cell on an iPad

Tags: google-sheets, mobile, ipad

How does one add a linebreak in a cell using an iPad. I tried wrapping text but it wouldn’t work any other solutions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using an app for iPhone and iPad. It might be on-topic on [apple.se].

Answer (score 3):

Per [David Wreesman](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/sz2vo186fPo):

> each line needs to be in quotes, with &char(10)& in between each line.
>
> For example, `="Dear Jane,"&char(10)&"I love you."&char(10)&"Love, Tom"` would turn into:
>
> Dear Jane,
> I love you.
> Love, Tom

Answer (score -2):

Or add `<br>` at the end.

E.g. `this is line a. <br> this is line b` which becomes

```
this is line a.
this is line b.
```